# Can't set a Dynamic Range without Error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to select a range in a macro, but I keep getting

"Compile error:"

"Expected: list separator or )"

I'm just trying to set a dynamic range using a variable I created before

```
With Sheets("Recon")
rownum3 = rownum2 + 2
rownum4 = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
set r3 = .range("K"&rownum3&":K"&rownum4)
```

This gives me the error

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, no I just didn't copy that part, it's the last line specifically. It's something wrong with the range I'm trying to set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As silly as it sounds, you need to add white space in your range (and also add an `end with`)

```
With Sheets("Recon")
rownum3 = rownum2 + 2
rownum4 = .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
set r3 = .range("K" & rownum3 & ":K" & rownum4)
end with
```

For some reason, when using variables, even when you separate them with the `&`, VBA doesn't like variables next to quotes.  Just add a space in between your `&` connectors and it should work okay.

One way to work around this non-auto-formatting issue is to use `Range(cells(),cells())`:

`Set r3 =.Range(.Cells(rownum3,11),.cells(rownum4,11))`

Cells() is `Cells([row #],[col. #])`, so wrapping that in a `Range()` is another way to do it (any my personal preferred way).

Comment: Oh, wow that's frustrating. Spent far too long reworking this.

Thanks!

Comment: @fordo19 - I've done the same! It doesn't make sense to me that VBA won't "auto format" when typing in stuff like that.  It does so for like `Cells(1,1)` , it'll automatically add a space between the comma and second 1...It just doesn't like these dynamic ranges.  See my edit too for another tip.